# Alternatives to service locator with opaque pointer in C

Tags: design, programming-practices, c, singleton, service-locator

I have a project in which one module keeps the state of the target device (things like current command level, but mostly status registers caches).

I'm aware that having a global public variable (Singleton pattern) is considered a very bad practice, and I understand why.

Instead, my approach is to use an opaque pointer (to a `struct`), allocate a single (`static`) instance of such `struct` in the `*.c` file (so it's not public) and provide it through a `Handle GetHandle(void)` function.

The above strategy is basically use the `adaptor pattern`, I still have a single instance. I have read that this is an anti-pattern as well.

**Is there any better why to design this module?**

Note: notice that in this project I can't use dynamic memory, so `malloc` etc. are forbidden

Comment: Make sure your sources for antipatterns are not object oriented in nature (which excludes C).  So structs should be able to copy values implicitly, any reason why you can't use the struct to store state and your functions interact with values in the struct?

Comment: Where have you read that having a single instance of X is an anti-pattern? Is there any chance you may have misunderstood what the author meant to say?

Comment: People talk about Singletons as a bad pattern all the time, but the simple truth is that almost every non-trivial application needs some place to save some global settings, and until that need goes away, there will always be some form of Singleton in common use.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch There is nothing preventing me from exposing the struct as it is, apart from that I do want to hide the struct's implementation so no one else can access its internal members, instead, they would need to use getters / setters etc. My idea is to apply the bridge pattern and keep interface and implementation decoupled.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau In several forums and articles on the internet. They basically say that it's a bad idea to have global state in an application. Although I agree in that the global state should be kept as minimal as possible, my application does need global state (hardware has 'global' registers).

Comment: You are confusing global state, singleton and single instance. Global state Is in the top level and accessible by anyone. Singleton is a class which itself ensures it is never instantiated twice usualy by putting Its instance into a static variable And making Its constructor private. Single instance is simply an object of a class you made sure to instantiate only once regardless if stored in local or global variable, but nothing should be preventing you from instantiating another one, whether it makes sense is another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have slightly misunderstood the articles about global state being an anti-pattern.

You file-scope variable is *not* what those articles consider to be "global state" anti-pattern. The global state that those articles warn about are variables that are accessible throughout the whole application and that can be written to by any part of the code without going through a common function that can apply a sanity check.

So, the fact that you use an opaque pointer and setter functions to change the stored state means that you have already applied the correct pattern to avoid the "global state" anti-pattern.

Having a single instance isn't a problem if two conditions are true

- it reflects the current requirements for the project (i.e., only a single target device needs to be supported now)
- it does not pervade your designs to the extent that it effectively becomes impossible to support multiple instances (i.e. multiple target devices) later on if the need arises. It is acceptable to have to do some rework, for example to identify which device you want to access the settings for, but it isn't good if you have to rewrite large portions of otherwise unrelated software just to support multiple devices.

  I get the feeling that your current design is already flexible enough in this regard.